# Android setTag equivalent in Swift

Tags: android, swift, view

I mean the method from the class View that allows to put a tag to an object of that class like this:

```
view.setTag(1)
```

Which would be the equivalent in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

You can set tag for view this way.

```
view.tag = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be late, but the actual answer given by @Muhammad Afzal is not exactly equivalent to `.setTag()` in Android.

Swift `.tag` only allows the use of `Int` values, while Android `.setTag()` allows the use of any `Object` value.

To get an equivalent functionality, one should create a simple custom class like the following:

```
public class UITagView:UIView{
    
    var Tag:Any?
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setTag(_ tag:Any){
        self.Tag = tag
    }
    
    func getTag()->Any{
        return self.Tag!
    }
}
```

If `view` is an instance of the class, then `view.setTag()` would be the the same in Android and Swift.

However, if the tags that you need are always Integers, it is easier to use `view.tag`, as @Muhammad Afzal said.

Note: As in Android, when recovering an object with the `.getTag()` method, it should be parsed to the class it belongs to (`view.getTag() as! SomeClass`).